# Dual Z-axis has different speeds (out of sync)

Tags: z-axis, stepper-driver, stepper, speed, dual-nozzle

The Z-axis has two stepper motors, I'm using MKS GEN L V2.1 mainboard with TMC 2209 Drivers. My problem is that the motors are out of sync. How can I get them to work together?

This is my code from the `configuration.h` file:

```
#define X_DRIVER_TYPE  TMC2209
#define Y_DRIVER_TYPE  TMC2209
#define Z_DRIVER_TYPE  TMC2209
//#define X2_DRIVER_TYPE A4988
//#define Y2_DRIVER_TYPE A4988
//#define Z2_DRIVER_TYPE A4988
//#define Z3_DRIVER_TYPE A4988
//#define Z4_DRIVER_TYPE A4988
#define E0_DRIVER_TYPE TMC2209
#define E1_DRIVER_TYPE TMC2209
//#define E2_DRIVER_TYPE A4988
//#define E3_DRIVER_TYPE A4988
//#define E4_DRIVER_TYPE A4988
//#define E5_DRIVER_TYPE A4988
//#define E6_DRIVER_TYPE A4988
//#define E7_DRIVER_TYPE A4988
```

Also here is the code from the `configuration_adv.h` file:

```
//
// For Z set the number of stepper drivers
//
#define NUM_Z_STEPPER_DRIVERS 2   // (1-4) Z options change based on how many

#if NUM_Z_STEPPER_DRIVERS > 1
  //#define Z_MULTI_ENDSTOPS
  #if ENABLED(Z_MULTI_ENDSTOPS)
    #define Z2_USE_ENDSTOP          _XMAX_
    #define Z2_ENDSTOP_ADJUSTMENT   0
    #if NUM_Z_STEPPER_DRIVERS >= 3
      #define Z3_USE_ENDSTOP        _YMAX_
      #define Z3_ENDSTOP_ADJUSTMENT 0
    #endif
    #if NUM_Z_STEPPER_DRIVERS >= 4
      #define Z4_USE_ENDSTOP        _ZMAX_
      #define Z4_ENDSTOP_ADJUSTMENT 0
    #endif
  #endif
#endif
```

and also this:

```
 // Microstep setting (Only functional when stepper driver microstep pins are connected to MCU.
#define MICROSTEP_MODES { 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16 } // [1,2,4,8,16]

#if HAS_TRINAMIC_CONFIG

  #define HOLD_MULTIPLIER    0.5  // Scales down the holding current from run current
  #define INTERPOLATE       true  // Interpolate X/Y/Z_MICROSTEPS to 256

  #if AXIS_IS_TMC(X)
    #define X_CURRENT       800        // (mA) RMS current. Multiply by 1.414 for peak current.
    #define X_CURRENT_HOME  X_CURRENT  // (mA) RMS current for sensorless homing
    #define X_MICROSTEPS     16    // 0..256
    #define X_RSENSE          0.11
    #define X_CHAIN_POS      -1    // <=0 : Not chained. 1 : MCU MOSI connected. 2 : Next in chain, ...
  #endif

  #if AXIS_IS_TMC(X2)
    #define X2_CURRENT      800
    #define X2_CURRENT_HOME X2_CURRENT
    #define X2_MICROSTEPS    16
    #define X2_RSENSE         0.11
    #define X2_CHAIN_POS     -1
  #endif

  #if AXIS_IS_TMC(Y)
    #define Y_CURRENT       800
    #define Y_CURRENT_HOME  Y_CURRENT
    #define Y_MICROSTEPS     16
    #define Y_RSENSE          0.11
    #define Y_CHAIN_POS      -1
  #endif

  #if AXIS_IS_TMC(Y2)
    #define Y2_CURRENT      800
    #define Y2_CURRENT_HOME Y2_CURRENT
    #define Y2_MICROSTEPS    16
    #define Y2_RSENSE         0.11
    #define Y2_CHAIN_POS     -1
  #endif

  #if AXIS_IS_TMC(Z)
    #define Z_CURRENT       800
    #define Z_CURRENT_HOME  Z_CURRENT
    #define Z_MICROSTEPS     16
    #define Z_RSENSE          0.11
    #define Z_CHAIN_POS      -1
  #endif

  #if AXIS_IS_TMC(Z2)
    #define Z2_CURRENT      800
    #define Z2_CURRENT_HOME Z2_CURRENT
    #define Z2_MICROSTEPS    16
    #define Z2_RSENSE         0.11
    #define Z2_CHAIN_POS     -1
  #endif

  #if AXIS_IS_TMC(Z3)
    #define Z3_CURRENT      800
    #define Z3_CURRENT_HOME Z3_CURRENT
    #define Z3_MICROSTEPS    16
    #define Z3_RSENSE         0.11
    #define Z3_CHAIN_POS     -1
  #endif

  #if AXIS_IS_TMC(Z4)
    #define Z4_CURRENT      800
    #define Z4_CURRENT_HOME Z4_CURRENT
    #define Z4_MICROSTEPS    16
    #define Z4_RSENSE         0.11
    #define Z4_CHAIN_POS     -1
  #endif

  #if AXIS_IS_TMC(E0)
    #define E0_CURRENT      900
    #define E0_MICROSTEPS    16
    #define E0_RSENSE         0.11
    #define E0_CHAIN_POS     -1
  #endif

  #if AXIS_IS_TMC(E1)
    #define E1_CURRENT      800
    #define E1_MICROSTEPS    16
    #define E1_RSENSE         0.11
    #define E1_CHAIN_POS     -1
  #endif

  #if AXIS_IS_TMC(E2)
    #define E2_CURRENT      800
    #define E2_MICROSTEPS    16
    #define E2_RSENSE         0.11
    #define E2_CHAIN_POS     -1
  #endif

  #if AXIS_IS_TMC(E3)
    #define E3_CURRENT      800
    #define E3_MICROSTEPS    16
    #define E3_RSENSE         0.11
    #define E3_CHAIN_POS     -1
  #endif

  #if AXIS_IS_TMC(E4)
    #define E4_CURRENT      800
    #define E4_MICROSTEPS    16
    #define E4_RSENSE         0.11
    #define E4_CHAIN_POS     -1
  #endif

  #if AXIS_IS_TMC(E5)
    #define E5_CURRENT      800
    #define E5_MICROSTEPS    16
    #define E5_RSENSE         0.11
    #define E5_CHAIN_POS     -1
  #endif

  #if AXIS_IS_TMC(E6)
    #define E6_CURRENT      800
    #define E6_MICROSTEPS    16
    #define E6_RSENSE         0.11
    #define E6_CHAIN_POS     -1
  #endif

  #if AXIS_IS_TMC(E7)
    #define E7_CURRENT      800
    #define E7_MICROSTEPS    16
    #define E7_RSENSE         0.11
    #define E7_CHAIN_POS     -1
  #endif
```

Finally, this picture represents the jumper set-up used.

[image: UART Jumper Set-up]

Comment: I'm not familiar with this board (have not used) but looking at the picture of the board, I see only one connector for the Z axis. Are you powering both from this or utilizing E1 to drive your 2nd stepper motor for the Z?

your configuration is telling Marlin that both steppers are on their own driver and yet you did not define Z2

Comment: when i define z2 driver i get this error
Error "TMC2208 or TMC2209 on Z2 requires Z2_HARDWARE_SERIAL or Z2_SERIAL_(RX|TX)_PIN

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the exact same issue, SKR1.4 Turbo with 2209's on i3 clone and it started when I tried to enable `G34` auto-alignment. I very briefly had it fixed by disabling the auto-alignment and I wish I knew how because now I can't even fix it with a fresh download of Marlin and no `G34` to begin with.

I took the gantry off and watched the motors turning because at first I thought they were trying to move opposite directions but in fact, they were just turning at different speeds.

Right now I have tried enabling all max end-stop pins as well as only min pins (using only the probe as Z end-stop) so far to no avail.

The good news for you is I think I see your problem.  E1 stepper should be commented out, Z2 is the one you want.  Let me know how/if it works.

Comment: I was having the same issue and this solution worked for me. I enabled Z2 and disabled E1. The Z motors were turning at different speeds until I did this. Running on Ender 3 Pro with BTT SKR E3 Turbo and Marlin 2.x Where Z1 motor is plugged into first Z port and Z2 motor is plugged into E1 port.

Comment: Many thanks, you saved my day. Enabled dual Z drivers on MKS Monster8. Now all good :)